# Should I use singular or plural to describe the steps applied to a list of items?

Tags: sentence-patterns

Example:

> She told me that her father worked in a manufacturer of recycling
>   equipment. They exported their machines practically all over the
>   world: Australia, Germany, Russia, South Africa, Brazil, Argentina,
>   among other countries. **Since her father was the only one in the firm
>   who spoke fluent English, he was the one responsible to fly to the
>   site, sell the machine, and provide basic training on how to operate
>   it.**

Or should it be?

> She told me that her father worked in a manufacturer of recycling
>   equipment. They exported their machines practically all over the
>   world: Australia, Germany, Russia, South Africa, Brazil, Argentina,
>   among other countries. **Since her father was the only one in the firm
>   who spoke fluent English, he was the one responsible to fly to the
>   sites, sell the machines, and provide basic training on how to operate
>   them.**

Comment: The bolded items are equally ok.  However, phrases  “worked in” and  “responsible to” are wrong.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for spotting that. What should I write instead?

Comment: @jwpat7 "worked at" and "responsible for flying..."?

Comment: Yes, those are ok, also "worked for"

Comment: Use **singular**. More than grammar, it's a question of good writing style.

Comment: @Kris Why is singular better for style?

Comment: That is a question for writersSE -- which is why I did not elaborate here on ELU -- else the question could be close voted as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

"She told me that her father worked *for* a manufacturer of recycling equipment. They exported their machines practically all over the world: Australia, Germany, Russia, South Africa, Brazil, *and* Argentina, among other countries. Since her father was the only one in the firm who spoke fluent English, he was the one responsible *for flying* to the sites, *selling* the machines, and *providing* basic training on how to operate them."

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the title question: it depends on the context.

In the passage you've indicated, you want plural. Prior to the bolded sentence, the writer makes reference to "their machines." Purely for the sake of consistency, the writer should continue with plural. Besides, using singular seems to indicate that their is only one site and one machine, which not only contradicts the information in the second sentence but also suggests a poor business model.